# migrate from django migrations to fastapi alembic

Tags: django, microservices, fastapi

I had a Django service which had an app called "User". This app has 2 tables in, which are being migrated to the database using Django migration system. In order to change the architecture from monolith to micro-service, I broke down User app and add the models and APIs in another Fastapi project. But I didn't separate the database and during this time, I was changing User tables in database using my previous Django project migration system. But now I want to break down tables in the database and move them to the new database. What is the best practices of doing this? And how can I change migrations from Django to alembic?

Comment: How many changes are we talking about? It's probably easier to update your SQLAlchemy models and then create alembic migrations from that instead of trying to do some sort of django vs alembic conversions. In the future you'll work with the SQLAlchemy database, so you'll create alembic migrations as necessary.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks. Actually my question is that how can I start using alembic from the middle of my migrations? not from scratch. Is that possible? I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's doable in any sensible way - the migrations are based on the underlying model classes and library, and Django model classes aren't compatible with SQLAlchemy model classes. So my suggestion is to use the django migrations to get the database up to a certain level, then define the SQLAlchemy model classes as representing that point in time, and then use alembic for future migrations (i.e. any changes from that point in time).